# Ordering on words

Tags: co.combinatorics, formal-languages, combinatorics-on-words

What are the known computation-friendly well-orderings on words from $A^*$, where $A$ is a finite alphabet, except the standard weightlex and syllable-order?

Comment: Do you want a partial or a total order?

Comment: Clearly, one can find computable well-orderings of this set of any infinite order type up to $\omega_1^{CK}$, provided $A$ is nonempty.

Comment: Recursive path orderings are very useful in rewriting systems.

Comment: Jean-Eric: partial orderings would be great, too.

Comment: Derek: am I right that recursive order is not a well-order? It seems not always possible to apply it to prove that a rewriting system is terminating.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three relevant references for partial wqo on words:

[1] F. D'Alessandro, S. Varricchio, [Well quasi-orders, unavoidable sets, and derivation systems](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ITA/ITA_2006__40_3/ITA_2006__40_3_407_0/ITA_2006__40_3_407_0.pdf), *RAIRO - Theoretical Informatics and Applications* **40** (2006) 407-426, [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/ita:2006019)

[2] A. Ehrenfeucht, D. Haussler, G. Rozenberg, [On regularity of context-free languages](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397582901244), *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **27** (1983) 311–332.

[3] M. Kunc, Regular solutions of language inequalities and well quasi-orders, *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **348** (2005) 277–293, ISSN 0304-3975, [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2005.09.018).

Answer (score 2):

There is a combination of lexicographic and graded lexicographic which
is quite useful for Groebner Bases for engineering applications.
These are admissible orders (in the sense of Mora).

Look for papers in the list

[http://math.ucsd.edu/~helton/BILLSPAPERSscanned/bibWEB.pdf](http://math.ucsd.edu/%7Ehelton/BILLSPAPERSscanned/bibWEB.pdf)

which have a co-author of Mark Stankus and have "Computer"
in their title.

Edward Green (from Virginia Tech) call this "noncommutative lex".